# dvips produces improperly-trimmed output for non-standard papersize

Tags: paper-size, units, dvips

### Note:

Rather than creating a new question that has almost the same code base, I rewrote my previous question. Because this issue is not specific to PSTricks, I changed the code so everybody can play with it.

---

I want to avoid using `pdfcrop` so I set the paper size to tightly suit my need in advance as follows.

```
% sample.tex
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage
[
paperwidth=144bp,%2in = 2x72bp = 144bp
paperheight=108bp,%1.5in = 1.5x72bp = 108bp
margin=0bp
]
{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor,calc}
\fboxsep=0bp
\fboxrule=2bp
\begin{document}
\noindent\fbox{\color{yellow}\rule{\paperwidth-2\fboxrule}{\paperheight-2\fboxrule}}%
\end{document}
```

or without using geometry.sty:

```
% sample.tex
\documentclass{minimal}
\paperwidth=144bp%2in = 2x72bp = 144bp
\paperheight=108bp%1.5in = 1.5x72bp = 108bp
\voffset=-72bp
\hoffset=-72bp
\special{papersize=144bp,108bp}
\usepackage{xcolor,calc}
\fboxsep=0bp
\fboxrule=2bp
\begin{document}
\noindent\fbox{\color{yellow}\rule{\paperwidth-2\fboxrule}{\paperheight-2\fboxrule}}%
\end{document}
```

Then I compiled it with `latex->dvips->ps2pdf` and I got a strange result as follows:

[image]

I also got EPS with strange bounding box as follows:

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
% Produced by xpdf/pdftops 3.02pl4
%%Creator: TeX
%%LanguageLevel: 2
%%DocumentSuppliedResources: (atend)
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 105 145
%%HiResBoundingBox: 0 0 104.994 144.018
%%EndComments
%%BeginProlog
%%BeginResource: procset xpdf 3.02pl4 0
%%Copyright: Copyright 1996-2007 Glyph & Cog, LLC
```

### Summary

I tested this using `pdflatex` with no problem. Herbert tested it using `xelatex` with no problem too. According to Herbert, there is a problem in `dvips`.

Comment: What final output file format do you require? (E)PS or PDF? You could avoid several steps if you would change from PSTricks to TikZ and use `pdflatex` (maybe in combination with the `preview` package or `standalone` class)

Comment: @xport: run the code snippets wioth `xelatex` and everything will be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ulrike mentions in a comment, dvips tries a known paper size that is near the specified dimensions. The call

```
dvips -t unknown sample -o
```

produces the following header:

```
%!PS-Adobe-2.0
%%Creator: dvips(k) 5.99 Copyright 2010 Radical Eye Software
%%Title: sample.dvi
%%CreationDate: Sun Jul 10 19:22:45 2011
%%Pages: 1
%%PageOrder: Ascend
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 144 108
%%EndComments
%DVIPSWebPage: (www.radicaleye.com)
%DVIPSCommandLine: dvips -t unknown sample -o
%DVIPSParameters: dpi=600
%DVIPSSource:  TeX output 2011.07.10:1911
%%BeginProcSet: tex.pro 0 0
%!
```

to be compared with the code obtained without `-t unknown`:

```
%!PS-Adobe-2.0
%%Creator: dvips(k) 5.99 Copyright 2010 Radical Eye Software
%%Title: sample.dvi
%%CreationDate: Sun Jul 10 19:19:40 2011
%%Pages: 1
%%PageOrder: Ascend
%%Orientation: Landscape
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 105 148
%%DocumentPaperSizes: a9
%%EndComments
%DVIPSWebPage: (www.radicaleye.com)
%DVIPSCommandLine: dvips sample -o
%DVIPSParameters: dpi=600
%DVIPSSource:  TeX output 2011.07.10:1911
%%BeginProcSet: tex.pro 0 0
%!
```

Comment: is it ok to always use `-t unknown` switch even when I use `a4paper`?

Comment: **geometry** issues a `\special` command; if geometry is not used the default paper size is used, which is letter, since the bounding box is `%%BoundingBox: 0 0 612 792`.

Comment: I should add that dvips uses the "distribution default", when `-t unknown` or any other options relative to paper is not given; on my machine it's A4, as customary with TeX Live.

Comment: To increase accuracy, pass `-D10000` to `dvips` and pass `-r10000` to ghostscript. See the detailed in [How should I express my length calculation to minimize rounding errors?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24168/how-should-i-express-my-length-calculation-to-minimize-rounding-errors/24177#24177).